# null value in python

Tags: python

As per definition, the None keyword is used to define a null value, or no value at all.
But why does:

```
inputs = [3, 0, 1, 2, None]
print(list(filter(None, inputs)))
```

return this list `[3,1,2]` and not `[3,0,1,2]`?

Comment: Don't mean to be rude, but reading the doc is the first thing you should do before posting here, cf [ask].

Comment: Related: [What is Truthy and Falsy, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the `filter` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

> If *function* is `None`, the identity function is assumed, that is,
>   all elements of *iterable* that are false are removed.

The identity function is basically:

```
def identity(something):
    return something
```

so filtering on this means that any value *that evaluates false-y* will be excluded from the output.

Then if you look at [truth-value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) you can see that, *as well as `None`*, `0` evaluates false-y in Python:

> Here are most of the built-in objects considered false:
>
> - constants defined to be false: `None` and `False`.
> - zero of any numeric type: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`
> - ...

Comment: From the https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter it says " If a function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed". but the element zero(0) in our case is not false.

Comment: @NathanKirui as I've also linked above, 0 is also considered false; I've added another quote.

Comment: @NathanKirui note that it just says *false* as opposed to *`False`*. This means objects that are *considered* to be false (not the constant `False`), and as the quote that jon provided you have the list of those objects

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @jonrsharpe explains why you get `[3,1,2]` instead of `[3,0,1,2]`. This is because 0 as well as None evaluates false-y in Python.

But in case you want the code to perform as expected, try this:

```
inputs = [3, 0, 1, 2, None]
print(list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, inputs)))
```

This should return the output as `[3,0,1,2]`